# Is is possible to use a printable image as a spreadsheet background

Tags: excel, vba, image, printing

is it possible to use an image from a disk as a printable excel spreadsheet background, which would not cover cells? I want to embed a snip image of a document onto worksheet, add text and calculation in particular cells on top of the image and be able to print it along with the values in cells.

I used the below code, but it does not put the image as a background. Even if transparency is lets say 35% the image is faded, so are the values in the cells.

```
Worksheets("tool").Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 432, 435).Select

With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .UserPicture "Z:\Capture.JPG"
    .Transparency = 0.35
    .TextureTile = msoFalse
    .TextureHorizontalScale = 1
    .TextureVerticalScale = 1
    .TextureAlignment = msoTextureTopLeft
End With
```

Is there any better way to achieve what I need please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would put the image on screen, without the transparency/fade etc.

```
Worksheets("tool").SetBackgroundPicture Filename:= "Z:\Capture.JPG"
```

And this would add the image as part of the document header, so it would print.

```
With Worksheets("tool").PageSetup
    .LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = "Z:\Capture.JPG"
    .LeftHeader = "&G"
End With
```

You could always use a paint program to edit the image to mimic the fade/transparency.